# send_email from php site hosted by profusehost

Tags: php, sendmail, mail-sender

I have my website in PHP hosted with profusehost.net. The problem is that the send_email functionality works correctly when i host it locally on my apache server with mercury mail. But now when i have hosted my pages on profusehost, the mail doesn't go with the send_email. Is there some settings which needs to be done with the hosting service provider or generally their mail clients are already configured? Please help...

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you don't have an instance of sendmail running on your hosting provider's server.  Take a look at Pear Mail; it will let you specify an alternate SMTP server:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php